# Disable scroll for off-canvas when open foundation 6.4

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 6.4 and I am trying to find the best approach to meet my requirements.

I am using the overlay off canvas located here [Foundation Docs overlay](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/off-canvas.html#off-canvas-transitions)

now I found that if i use the following in my off canvas overlay

```
data-content-scroll="false"
```

it will prevent the scroll of body content. but the issue it provides is that when ever you open the menu the prevent scroll makes it jump to the top all content. is there any way around this?

I noticed that when menu is not triggered it classes is-closed and when its open is classes is-open is there a way i can get this to not scroll all the way to the top when menu opens?

**UPDATE!**
I figured out why it is giving the issue, because i was forcing the scroll bar because I didnt want the shift. is there a way to force scrollbar but not make it scroll back to the top when I open menu?